# Comparison of Symmetric Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory

The Problem:

There is a unitary space $(V,<.,.>)$, $D \subseteq V $ a subspace and $  A,B : V \supseteq  D\to V $ are two symmetric linear operators. Show that if:

$<Ax , x> $$=$ $<Bx , x>$ $\forall x \in D$

Then $A = B$

My Solution:
$<Ax , x> $$=$ $<Bx , x>$

so $<Ax , x> - <Bx , x> = 0$

and $<Ax-Bx , x> = 0$

and $<(A-B)x , x> = 0$

Which leaves $A-B=0$ and therefore $A=B$.

All just using the properties of symmetric linear operators and inner products. The problem is, this proof seems too simple to me but I can't see a mistake. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's correct- but there is some gap.

You have to prove that $<Cx,x>=0$ for all $x$ implies that $C=0$. Note that this isn't true in general:
Take the matrix with $a_{11}=0,a_{12}=-1,a_{13}=1,a_{14}=0$ for instance.
Here you have to use the symmetry of $A$ and $B$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it. I have actually already shown that but left it out for brevity.

Comment: Well- that's all that is there to this question. Nothing too deep :-).

Comment: Okay, I thought I had shown it already but it turns out I haven't. Do you have any other tips to help me? I have a feeling I might be over complicating things and am missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Need to show :

If $A$ is symmetric and $<Ax,x>=0$ for all $x$ then $A=0$.

$<A(x+y),x+y>=0 \implies <Ax,y>+<Ay,x>=0 \implies 2real(<Ax,y>)=0$. Similarly show that im($<Ax,y>=0$). Thus, $<Ax,y>=0$ for all $x,y$ and hence $A=0$.

This trick is called polarization. (Sometimes polarization identity).

Comment: Thanks again Voldemort! You've been a great help.